# Map Array of raw Datas in different scales to SVG Elements coordinates (Polylines, Circles, Paths) in order to build a Chart

Tags: svg, charts, data-visualization, polyline

I need to do a line chart using a `polyline` in `SVG` pretty like [this](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg/#article-header-id-5).

I have got a set of data that are **float** and **with small differences**, not the classics 10, 23, ...

Here's an example of the datas that comes from the API:

```
let prices = [{priceUsd: 0.12864351622594805, time: 1550793600000, date: "2019-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"}, {priceUsd: 0.1289917968298398, time: 1552867200000, date: "2019-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"}, {priceUsd: 0.12906372519586895, time: 1544918400000, date: "2018-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"},{priceUsd: 0.1293249579162421, time: 1551312000000, date: "2019-02-28T00:00:00.000Z"},{priceUsd: 0.12935590989241688, time: 1556668800000, date: "2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

So, I can't figure out how to correctly set the SVG **[viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)**, **[preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)**, other attributes and of course the point of the **`polyline`** in order to render a safe and complete **chart**.

### Minimal, Reproducible Example

How to see `5` yellow circles (but can be more) in proportion inside a square of 100 X 100? `cx` is `time` and `cy` si `priceUsd`.

```js
let history = [
  {priceUsd: 0.12864351622594805, time: 1550793600000, date: "2019-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"}, 
  {priceUsd: 0.1289917968298398, time: 1552867200000, date: "2019-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"}, 
  {priceUsd: 0.12906372519586895, time: 1544918400000, date: "2018-12-16T00:00:00.000Z"},
  {priceUsd: 0.1293249579162421, time: 1551312000000, date: "2019-02-28T00:00:00.000Z"},
  {priceUsd: 0.12935590989241688, time: 1556668800000, date: "2019-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
];
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" style="background-color: red">
    <circle cx="1550793600000" cy="0.12864351622594805" r="5" fill="yellow"></circle>
    <circle cx="1552867200000" cy="0.1289917968298398" r="5" fill="yellow"></circle>
    <circle cx="1544918400000" cy="0.12906372519586895" r="5" fill="yellow"></circle>
    <circle cx="1551312000000" cy="0.1293249579162421" r="5" fill="yellow"></circle>
    <circle cx="1556668800000" cy="0.12935590989241688" r="5" fill="yellow"></circle>
</svg>
```

### References

- http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/02/creating-interactive-graphs-with-svg-part-1/
- https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-charts-with-svg
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: I think we're going to need a [mcve] rather than a single line of code here.

Comment: @RobertLongson please checks the edit. If you need more information I can provide.

Comment: It's unlikely using such really large and really small numbers will work well for you. You need to scale them to something smaller in the first case and larger in the second

Comment: Thanks, I thought that but I thought also that I possibly can set the coordinate system using viewport and preserveAspectRatio. This for not insert too much logic between the API and the components and also be free to scale the chart without scaling the values.

Comment: There are various browsers that won't really work for. If you use huge or small numbers you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. So how about using Percentage in cx and cy calculated from the maximum and minimum members of the array?